# Compatibility of new Acer Aspire M3 with Nvidia GT 640M Kepler GPU with hybrid graphics?

Tags: laptop, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

A new Acer Aspire M3 with Nvidia GT 640M Kepler GPU (Nvidia Optimus) has been announced:
http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/13/2868854/acer-aspire-timeline-ultra-m3-announce-kepler-gt-640M

```
[...] the company claims the Ultra M3 can still manage eight hours of battery life for 
normal tasks using Nvidia's Optimus graphics switching solution [...]
```

Any ideas if this model should be Linux hybrid-graphics compatible given the graphics card in it? Are the proprietary Nvidia Linux drivers going to be working for it? Should Bumblebee work for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case hybrid graphics work like a charm with bumblebee and kubuntu 12.04.

I've used the instructions in the wiki and worked with no problems.

[ubuntu wiki bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron N7110  with seperate Nvidia GTX520m card. Also I have ~25 mins more battery life than with windows.

Answer (score 1):

I own an Acer Aspire M3 with Nvidia GT 640M up to now I was unable to activate the nvidia GPU, my Ubuntu 12.04 just use the integrated Intel graphic card:

- Bumblebee does not work
- Proprietary nvidia driver are not recommended

From the nvidia driver download [page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-295.53-driver.html):

"... Some designs incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available..."

Comment: Would it be possible for you to submit your DSDT details as described here? https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Comment: This is my generated [DSDT file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12792633/Acer-Aspire_M3-581TG.tar.gz), I will try the mentioned guide [ubuntu wiki bumble](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and I notify you about the results.

Comment: Hopefully the developers in the list will pick up the relevant information from the file. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Considering buying one of [these](http://www.acerdirect.co.uk/Acer_Aspire_Timeline_Ultra_M3_Core_i7_Ultrabook_NX.RYKEK.004/version.asp), but put off by the nvidia thing. So yours works - great - do external monitors work? Do you know if the BIOS set up has the ability to disable the NVIDIA discrete graphics card? It's a nightmare buying laptop for Linux right now.

Comment: is not possible to disable the NVIDIA discrete graphics card in the bios. But external monitor works via the hdmi output (audio & video).